# Skip unknown command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

In a current application I have, the incoming command line parameters are parsed on several "levels".

At the highest level I only wish to parse some options and leave the rest to "lower levels". however, all libraries I've tried so far (Common Cli, args4j, JOpt, gnu.jargs) al throw an "unknown option" exception when I'm trying to feed them, well, unknown options.

I really don't want to write a yet another command line parsing class. Is there a library/class that parses these options and skips over unknown options?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post example how did you try to do it?

Answer (score 1):

jopt lets you specify a default value. No exception is thrown.

```java
parser.accepts("count").withOptionalArg().ofType(Integer.class).defaultsTo(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution.

```
public static BiFunction<String[],CmdLineParser,String[]> stripUnusedArgs=(args,parser)->{

    List<String> accepteds=parser.getOptions().stream().map(opt->opt.option.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> stripedArgs=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i< args.length;i++){
        if(accepteds.contains(args[i])){
            stripedArgs.add(args[i]);
            stripedArgs.add(args[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return stripedArgs.toArray(new String[0]);
};
```

And then to use it:

```
CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(CustomArgsObject);
stripUnusedArgs.apply(args,parser);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Args4j I think the `SubCommandHandler` could be just good enough. https://args4j.kohsuke.org/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/spi/SubCommandHandler.html